# Format bar margins in bar chart on SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to "squish together" the bars in a bar chart because I need to put a larger set of elements in the chart. How can I shrink the margins between each bar? I don't need to change the side margins, just the gaps between the bars. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this information.  It worked for me.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seanboon/archive/2008/10/31/ssrs-and-microsoft-chart-control-chart-how-to-change-the-width-of-bars-and-columns.aspx

Comment: I did find that a little while back and it worked just fine. But thanks anyway for dropping it on here so other people can pick it up, guess I should have done that too.

Comment: Any chance you can mark as answered, so others know this technique works? Thanks :-)